# Accessing members of an enum entry in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Given:

```
enum class Foo {
    BAR,
    BAZ { fun qux(foo: Any) {} }
}
```

It appears to be legal code, but when I try to access `qux()` like so:

```
val foo = Foo.BAZ
foo.qux("blah")
```

...it doesn't work as the member function is not visible.

Is there a way I can access `qux()` outside of the enum class? If not, then what would be a use case for a custom member of an enum entry?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it to implement interfaces and abstract methods, but since those body blocks are [anonymous classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#anonymous-classes) You won't be able to explicitly access per-entry values.

Perhaps what you're looking for can be achieved by using [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html)?

Comment: I know I can have an abstract function for the entire enum class that I can override in entries. I was hoping to avoid that. Sealed classes would work as well. At this point I'm curious what functionality having an enum entry member brings. I guess I could use the member within the scope of the entry...